# Less. Конвертация px в rem

Tags: javascript, less

Здравствуйте.

Интересует возможность автоматического пересчета в другие единицы измерения с помощью параметризированных переменных. 
Например, создаётся переменная типа **@value()**, и когда в круглые скобки прописываешь значение в **px**, она отдаёт результат в **rem** в свойство, в котором указана.
Что-то типа:

```
.block {
  width: @value(100);
    }
```

После компиляции:

```
.block {
  width: 6.25rem;
}
```

Использование миксинов позволяет определять только конкретные свойства, меня же интересует возможность именно универсального применения.

На англоязычном стаке есть похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510224/convert-px-to-em-in-less), там приводят код, делающий подобные преобразования, но так и не понял куда его надо вставить

Comment: Куда-нибудь **до** стилей. И все указания размеров заменить на вызовы этой функции.

Comment: Куда-нибудь - не вполне конкретно. Можно ли подробнее?

Comment: Ох, извините, я немного застрял в мире Sass, думал, что тут тоже есть синтаксис определения функций. Как выяснилось, нету. Пишут, что нужно добавить его в настройки сборки LESS, где они находятся -- зависит от системы сборки, там приводится пример для `grunt-contrib-less`, какая у вас?

Comment: Использую gulp.